# Mysql date compare error LIMIT 0,30

Tags: mysql, date, compare

I want to compare my date with data in mysql db, but i have an error " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE '2014-06-09' >= date_start AND '2014-06-11' <= date_end) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4".

```
SELECT name
FROM seminars
WHERE allowed_users LIKE '%1%'
AND (WHERE '2014-06-09' >= date_start AND '2014-06-11' <= date_end)
```

Comment: You've got `WHERE` used twice.  Just delete the second.

Comment: Not only you're using `WHERE` incorrectly, you're treating strings as `Date` as well.

Comment: @alfasin comparing a date as a string always works for me in MySQL.

Comment: @JeremyMiller that's not MySQL "magic" - it works for you cause you maintain specific format which respects String comparison as well, for example: `yyyy-mm-dd`. The fact that it works doesn't mean it's good practice. The day you'll want to do anything that has "date behavior" (like adding a day) with it you'll fail.

Comment: @alfasin Ah, so if the locale is different (or such), then the formatting will be different and queries would not perform as expected.  Thanks... I'm learning quite a bit while trying to help, tonight.

Answer (score 1):

You have used "where" keyword twice which is creatin problem. Also suggest you to use date function in case you are storing datetime in your start and end date column, to ensure no records are skipped.

```
SELECT name
FROM seminars
WHERE allowed_users LIKE '%1%'
AND ( '2014-06-09' >= date(date_start) AND '2014-06-11' <= date(date_end))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM seminars
WHERE allowed_users LIKE '%1%'
AND '2014-06-09' >= date_start AND '2014-06-11' <= date_end
```